# Minimum legible font size and internationalization

Tags: html, css, internationalization, accessibility, font-size

Is there any way to determine a base minimum font size for a given language or font?

I've been looking for some way to tell programatically if a browser font/glyph size is perceptually equal across different languages? For example, I've seen that Thai fonts are painfully small compared to Latin or Japanese (probably because of Thai's enormous ascenders force everything to scale down to fit in each glyph's bounding box). And I suspect that *lots and lots of other languages* have very different "minimum legible size" values from Latin fonts.

Here is an example of the problem, first with clearly legible English text (in the blue buttons). Below that is a picture of equivalent Thai text, which has identical styling but is barely legible.

[image: Thai question with English answers]
[image: English question with Thai answers]

This shows Thai and Latin fonts. When Thai and Latin text have an equal `font-size` applied to them, Thai is perceptually "too small" (this is more obvious at smaller font sizes). Increasing it by 15% gives something closer to actual Thai presentation:

[image: Thai and Latin with equal and adjusted font sizes]

I can use the CSS Object Model's `element.getBoundingClientRect()` to find the dimensions of shapes and elements, but I know of no way of measuring inside a font. And `CanvasRenderingContext2D.measureText()` currently only gives `width` information.

Is there any method / API (in the browser or not) for determining a sort of "base font size" that perhaps discounts ascenders and descenders or even gives a suggested base font size?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it's not the question of i18n, but a11y (that is accessibility). You see, if you set the font too small some people (me included) will not be able to read it.
Of course there are cases like Traditional Chinese where 12 point is an absolute minimum because otherwise some strokes will not be clearly seen. But it's hard to give exact numbers for all languages without actual UI testing.

Comment: Thanks. That is actually a better way of looking at the problem. I've retagged the question. For me, the problem is one of "balance of design across character sets", but I only became aware of this because the font-size I was using was illegible to my crappy eyes when using Thai; so this was certainly an accessibility problem from the beginning. It is still an internationalization issue though because I suspect other charsets will present this same problem, but don't know what they are. And I am still searching for some resource for sorting this problem out.